# iOS Universal Link doesn't work on some devices

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I have set all requirements for Universal Link according to Apple documentation. When i started test on real devices, link doesn't work for some of them. All devices on iOS 11.1.1 so it's not about OS Version. Some devices can open app and when i long press on link shows "Open in xxx App" but some devices not open app also not showing option on long press. Already changed `Build Configuration` to `Release`.

Is there anyway to find reason of that? Could factory reset solve this problem?

Comment: Will this help https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/273082/all-the-app-links-deep-links-are-broken-after-a-reboot ?

Comment: @OleksiyIvanov unfortunality no my friend :( It seems it's iOS bug

Comment: any solution? was this only during testflight, or also when already published? I have the same, some testers don't have the link opening in app, some do.

Comment: seeing this again on iOS 12.1. can anyone confirm \ deny this is only happening on TestFlight on not on production apps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in my case was Reseting Entitlement. More on this you can read [here](https://medium.com/mobile-growth/the-things-i-hate-and-you-should-know-about-apple-universal-links-5beb15f88a29).

Basically, if the user has ever chosen to open the link in safari using the top button after opening a deeplink, he will always be pointed to the site instead of the app, unless he manually chooses to open the app.

The problem with the explanation above though is that I haven't managed to revert this Resetting Entitlement. At least it explains the issue and how the links work

Answer (score 0):

as far as I experienced It's a bug.
I think if you follow this steps it should be fixed:

1 ) removing the application from Xcode (Devices and Simulator section`command + shift + 2` )

2 ) press the `-` button for that specific application.

Last but not least,it would be great if you do  `Restart` or `Reset All Settings`  before this staps.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your Apple-App-Site-Association file is correct places on your domain.
you can do the same via the [link](https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/)